# How do I iterate over a Mac Resource Fork

Tags: objective-c, macos, macos-carbon, resource-files, file-forks

I want to be able to iterate over a Mac OS Resource Fork so a Cocoa Window can show how many resources there is for a specific resource type (I.e., `'MADI'`).
I want to use the (yes, I know they're deprecated) Carbon Resource Manager functions. The only way I can think of to get all the values is to brute-force my way from `SHORT_MIN` to `SHORT_MAX` for each OSType to check for.

Part of the problem is that there's no documentation in the header, and I am loathe to download the legacy API reference due to its size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I got `Get1IndResource()` and `Get1Resource()` mixed up in my brain.

`Get1IndResource()` iterates based on the order a specific resource is in a resource file/fork, starting from 1 instead of 0 (most likely from when the Mac API was written/used by Pascal). `Get1Resource()` gets resource data from the resource ID number.